# Create n-dimensional random Point given Euclidean Distance

Tags: python, vector, point, euclidean-distance

Given a point (`p`) and a Euclidean Distance (`d`), generate a random point (`m`) such that the Euclidean Distance between `p` and `m` is `d`.

This is easily to visualise and in 2D where the result set is just a circle of radius `d` around point `p`. However, the solution needs to work for any n-dimensional point (I am working with length 32 currently).

There is this StackOverflow thread for doing something similar for Cosine Similarity: [Create random vector given cosine similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52916699/create-random-vector-given-cosine-similarity)

Answer (score 0):

For generating a random point (`m`) that is at a given distance (`d`) from a initial point (`p`) you can use the following:

```
M = P + v
where v = d*u
and u = (u1, u2, u3, ...) ; |u| = 1 --> |v| = d
```

(v and u are vectors of n-dimensional lenght, and |x| means the modulus of x)

So for generating a random point we only need to generate a random unit vector (`u`), from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283080/random-unit-vector-in-multi-dimensional-space) we can get a simple code that generates a random unit vector. We only need to multiply the vector (be careful because is a list) with the distance, and add it to the point p.

Here is the final implementation (not fully compact for better comprehension):

```py
from random import gauss


def make_rand_vector(dims):
    vec = [gauss(0, 1) for i in range(dims)]
    mag = sum(x**2 for x in vec) ** .5
    return [x/mag for x in vec]

def gen_random_point(p, d):
    u = make_rand_vector(len(p))  # generating a random unit vector
    v = [i*d for i in u]  # scaling the vector by d
    m = [i+k for i, k in zip(p, v)]  # adding the vector and the initial point
    return m
```